# Loosing Sqlite on flutter update

Tags: sqlite, flutter, installation, updating

I am installing a flutter app on a device using `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` and `flutter install`. The app uses SQLite which is erased on installing a new version of the app. Is it possible to upgrade the app keeping the SQLite database intact?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is to use `adb install` instead of `flutter install`. Thus:

```
adb install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
```